# Lower Deployment Target on Project with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podfile, deployment-target

I've been creating a project with the default development target (I believe it was 11.1). For whatever reason, I thought itd be a good idea to lower the development target to 10.0 which created 36 errors mostly of my classes not recognizing pods I was importing.

I don't remember the original target, but I would like to know if its at all possible or even practical to lower my development target, while not destroying my cocoapod integration. In this case I do not set a global platform on my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'My Project' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Chris Heria
```

Any tips?

Comment: Why don’t you change back your development target?

Comment: Yes, that solved my issue. But my question is how to lower the deployment target effectively.